# When TestComplete is opened I Could not create Java Virtual Machine

Tags: jvm, testcomplete

Problem Description:
My Java application is launched using a .cmd file from a network path. It gets launched without any issues. But if I open TestComplete tool and then try to open the application, I get an error as "Could not create the Java Virtual Machine" as a popup with ok button. Upon clicking ok, the application process gets closed. Infact there is only option to click Ok:).

Environment Info:
I use TestComplete to automate a Windows based java application. The Java application is developed using Java 1.6 and TestComplete version is 10.5. The system is of Windows 7 64 bit. JRE in the local machine is of version 1.7

Understandings by googling:
My application is needs a JVM (Java Virtual Machine) with a heap memory of 1GB. TestComplete is somehow not letting it happen.

Trials Attempted:
1.Tried editing the heap size in Java control panel located in control panel with -Xmx1024m.

Does something rings for someone?

Comment: Can you clarify how do you start the application when working with TestComplete? Also, it would be great if post here the CMD file or at least the command-line you use to run your application.

Comment: Thank you for spending time on this issue Dmitry Nikolaev.

Comment: Actually I can't share the CMD file here. Sorry for that.

Comment: The way I start the application is by manually double clicking the CMD file located in the network path. No any parameters are passed to it while running it.

Comment: Well, it is quite hard to help without knowing HOW the application is started. The CMD file should run the tested application using a specific command line. Can you post this line here? If this information is sensitive, I would recommend you contacting the SmartBear Customer Care team: http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete